# Scaling a sprite in main loop

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I want to create a game where circles are generated randomly over the surface and start to grow. When 2 circles touch each other the game ends. So, everything is working except the resizing of the sprite during a loop. When I use `transform.scale` I get something like this:

[image: Resizing using "transform.scale]

Then I found `transform.smoothscale` in the doc. I used changed my code to use this and then it looked like this:

[image: Resizing using "transform.smoothscale"]

I also tried to use `Rect.inflate` but this did nothing to my sprite. And I tried `Rect.infalte_ip` and if I use this, the sprite won't grow it is more likely to move out of the frame. Any ideas on how I can make these Sprite grow in place and that they resize how they should?

```
class Bubbles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.image_scale = 100
    self.image_scale_factor = 1
    self.image = resources.BUBBLE_SKIN[0].convert_alpha()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.image_scale, self.image_scale))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = (random.randrange(Settings.object_range_limit + (self.image_scale//2), (Settings.width - Settings.object_range_limit - self.image_scale)))
    self.rect.centery = (random.randrange(Settings.object_range_limit + (self.image_scale//2), (Settings.height - Settings.object_range_limit - self.image_scale)))

    self.growth_rate = random.randint(1, 4)

def update(self):
    self.image_scale += self.growth_rate
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.image_scale, self.image_scale))
```

Comment: Are you scaling the original sprite or are you gradually scaling the sprite?

Comment: Please show some code so we can help you

Comment: I saved the image of the sprite in "self.image". And i used this variable to scale the image.

Comment: Do you continuously something like `self.image`= pygame.trasnform.smoothscale(self.image, ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must scale the original sprite, instead of gradually scaling the sprite. Every time you scale the sprint, the quality degrades. If you scale the sprite gradually, the quality gets worse and worse. Store the sprite to an attribute `orignal_image` and scale the `orignal_image`.

If you want to scale the image by the center of the image, you must update the `rect` attribute after scaling the image with the new image size.
See [How do I scale a PyGame image (Surface) with respect to its center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919826/how-do-i-scale-a-pygame-image-surface-with-respect-to-its-center/59919909#59919909)

```py
class Bubbles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
    
        self.image = resources.BUBBLE_SKIN[0].convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(
            self.image, (self.image_scale, self.image_scale))

        self.original_image =  self.image

    def update(self):
        self.image_scale += self.growth_rate
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(
            self.original_image, (self.image_scale, self.image_scale))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked so far. And is there a way to fix my other problem that i stated in my question regarding the "resizing in place"?

Comment: @Lilin20 I have no idea what you are talking about. Your question is unclear. Do you want to set an initial scale?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. So when i scale the sprite now, it works and it does not deform. But while it scales, the sprite moves to my bottom right corner.

Comment: @Lilin20 I've extended the answer.